# query to list product lines of products whose quantity in stock is the least

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: based off of this model]

```
SELECT ProductLines.productLine, COUNT(quantityInStock)
FROM ProductLines JOIN
     Products
     USING (productLine)
GROUP BY customerName
HAVING COUNT(quantityInStock) =
           (SELECT MIN(quantityStock)
            FROM (SELECT COUNT(quantityInStock) AS quantityStock

                   FROM ProductLines JOIN
                        Products
                        USING(productLine)
                   GROUP BY Products.productLine
                  ) AS tableX
         );
```

I am getting an error on the SELECT statement ( not valid at the position but I have no idea how to fix it or if this is right)

Comment: Your query makes no sense at all.  You are counting a quantity column instead of summing.  You are aggregating by one column, but selecting another.  Very unclear.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query